# Elasticsearch not starting, but throwing ReceiveTimeoutTransportException

Tags: spring-mvc, elasticsearch, spring-data

I am trying to use elastic search with java api, but when i try to run application, i am getting following exception.

```
   18:13:52.378 [elasticsearch[Fallen One][generic][T#1]] INFO  org.elasticsearch.client.transport - [Fallen One] failed to get local cluster state for [#transport#-1][integra][inet[/127.0.0.1:9300]], disconnecting...
org.elasticsearch.transport.ReceiveTimeoutTransportException: [][inet[/127.0.0.1:9300]][cluster/state] request_id [52] timed out after [5001ms]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$TimeoutHandler.run(TransportService.java:356) [elasticsearch-1.0.1.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_51]
18:13:52.381 [elasticsearch[Fallen One][generic][T#1]] DEBUG org.elasticsearch.transport.netty - [Fallen One] disconnected from [[#transport#-1][integra][inet[/127.0.0.1:9300]]]
18:13:52.391 [elasticsearch[Fallen One][generic][T#3]] DEBUG org.elasticsearch.transport.netty - [Fallen One] connected to node [[#transport#-1][integra][inet[/127.0.0.1:9300]]]
```

Code for connecting to elastic search is

```
private String[] esNodes =  { "127.0.0.1:9300" };
 protected TransportClient buildClient() throws Exception {
        Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
                .put("client.transport.sniff", true)
                .put("client.transport.ignore_cluster_name",true).build();

        TransportClient client = new TransportClient(settings);
        for (int i = 0; i < esNodes.length; i++) {
            client.addTransportAddress(toAddress(esNodes[i]));
        }
        return client;
    }

    private InetSocketTransportAddress toAddress(String address) {
        if (address == null) return null;

        String[] splitted = address.split(":");
        int port = 9300;
        if (splitted.length > 1) {
            port = Integer.parseInt(splitted[1]);
        }
        return new InetSocketTransportAddress(splitted[0], port);
    }
```

can any one kindly help me, i am new to elastic search and have no idea how to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am using this code to connect to my elasticsearch and its pretty well working.

```
Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
            .put("cluster.name", clusterName).build();
this.client = new TransportClient(settings)
            .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(ipAddress,9300));
```

Where ipAddress and Clustername are argument of my function.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the network on your laptop. Check if you can connect to localhost. Another thing you could try is start two elasticsearch instances with the same configuration to see if they connect. Finally have a look at the network part of elasticsearch.yml. When having network problems on a local machine I usually try the following two options:

network.host: localhost
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["localhost"]

Answer (score -1):

I think Elastic search server is Not started..  Try to hit in browser or curl comments..  If it works..  Try the above code..

NOTE:IF YOUR JAVA API JAR VERSION DIFFERS ALSO LL RAISE PROB.. ( get java api version same as ES version

Note : elasticsearch java api helps you connect to with elasticsearch..  But its can't start a elasticsearch node using api..

Your code is good..  It's Vry standard too..

Comment: The people who down voted , specify the reason please.!